# Use of async in Amazon Lambda example?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I'm reviewing Amazon Lambda's example code for resizing images in S3 buckets.  [Example code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-create-function.html) (snipped for clarity):

```
// Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
async.waterfall([
  function download(next) {
    // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
    s3.getObject({Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey}, next);
  },
  function tranform(response, next) {
    gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
      // do resize with image magic
    }
  }
]);
//... more handling code
```

...shows they are using async waterfall.  However, each of these ordered steps seems to rely on the results of the previous function.  So in essence, this is a sequential operation.

What is the benefit of using async waterfall here?  Is this something to do with Lambda's execution engine at Amazon, or just a sensible design decision in node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a sensible design decision as you described it.
Instead of getting into the ["callback hell"](http://callbackhell.com/) the author of the example basically flattened the code by using `waterfall`.

The alternative code would look like this:

```
s3.getObject({Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey}, function(response){
  gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
  // do resize with image magic
  }
});
```

Which is less readable, and can get much more complex and much less readable as steps are added to the processing.